# common_ancestor function for nested tree dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a function called "common_ancestor()" that takes two inputs: the first a list of string taxa names, and the second a phylogenetic tree dictionary. It should return a string giving the name of the taxon that is the closest common ancestor of all the
species in the input list. Already made a separate function called "list_ancestors" that gives me the general ancestors of the elements in the list. Also, have a dictionary I am working with.

```
    tax_dict = { 
'Pan troglodytes': 'Hominoidea',       'Pongo abelii': 'Hominoidea', 
'Hominoidea': 'Simiiformes',           'Simiiformes': 'Haplorrhini', 
'Tarsius tarsier': 'Tarsiiformes',     'Haplorrhini': 'Primates',
'Tarsiiformes': 'Haplorrhini',         'Loris tardigradus':'Lorisidae',
'Lorisidae': 'Strepsirrhini',          'Strepsirrhini': 'Primates',
'Allocebus trichotis': 'Lemuriformes', 'Lemuriformes': 'Strepsirrhini',
'Galago alleni': 'Lorisiformes',       'Lorisiformes': 'Strepsirrhini',
'Galago moholi': 'Lorisiformes'
} 

def halfroot(tree):
    taxon = random.choice(list(tree))
    result = [taxon]
    for i in range(0,len(tree)): 
        result.append(tree.get(taxon))
        taxon = tree.get(taxon)
    return result


def root(tree):
    rootlist = halfroot(tree)
    rootlist2 = rootlist[::-1]
    newlist = []
    for e in range(0,len(rootlist)):
        if rootlist2[e] != None:
        newlist.append(rootlist2[e])
    return newlist[0]


def list_ancestors(taxon, tree):
    result = [taxon]
    while taxon != root(tree):
        result.append(tree.get(taxon))
        taxon = tree.get(taxon)
    return result

def common_ancestors(inputlist,tree)
    biglist1 = []
    for i in range(0,len(listname)):
        biglist1.append(list_ancestors(listname[i],tree))
        "continue so that I get three separate lists where i can cross reference all elements from the first list to every other list to find a common ancestor "
```

the result should look something like

```
  print(common_ancestor([’Hominoidea’, ’Pan troglodytes’,’Lorisiformes’], tax_dict)
  Output: ’Primates’"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please first show what you've tried, and where you're coming up short.  Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like Homework Help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to collect the all ancestors for each species, place them in a set and then get an intersection to get what they have in common:

```
def common_ancestor(species_list, tree):
    result = None  # initiate a `None` result
    for species in species_list:  # loop through each species in the species_list
        ancestors = {species}  # initiate the ancestors set with the species itself
        while True:  # rinse & repeat until there are leaves in the ancestral tree
            try:
                species = tree[species]  # get the species' ancestor
                ancestors.add(species)  # store it in the ancestors set
            except KeyError:
                break
        # initiate the result or intersect it with ancestors from the previous species
        result = ancestors if result is None else result & ancestors
    # finally, return the ancestor if there is only one in the result, or None
    return result.pop() if result and len(result) == 1 else None

print(common_ancestor(["Hominoidea", "Pan troglodytes", "Lorisiformes"], tax_dict))
# Primates
```

You can use the 'middle' part of this function for the `list_ancestors()`, too - there is no need to complicate it by trying to find the tree's root:

```
def list_ancestors(species, tree, include_self=True):
    ancestors = [species] if include_self else []
    while True:
        try:
            species = tree[species]
            ancestors.append(species)
        except KeyError:
            break
    return ancestors
```

Of course, both rely on a valid ancestral tree dictionary - if some of the ancestors were to recurse on themselves or if there is a breakage in the chain it won't work. Also, if you were to do a lot of these operations it might be worth to turn your flat dictionary into a proper tree.